# Conditional distributions being Gaussian implies joint distribution is also Gaussian?

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

I have no idea how to show the joint distribution is gaussian besides setting up linear equation and try to solve for Σ and μ. How is the proof supposed to be easy?

Comment: Are $w_1,...,w_t,v_1,...,v_t$ independent?

Comment: @DominikKutek Yes, I think they are independent.

Comment: Then, isn't it that $s_1,...,s_t,y_1,...,y_t$ are linear combinations of $w_1,...,w_t,v_1,...,v_t$ and since vector $(w_1,...,w_t,v_1,...,v_t)$ is gaussian (here we need independence, or some information that will help us to conclude such vector is gaussian), then $(s_1,...,s_t,y_1,...,y_t)$ will be gaussian, too, as a linear transformation of gaussian vector.